# How to set/redefine variable in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, external, redefine

How can I re-define variable in external js file '*js/sample.js*'?
The main idea was not touch core file and be possible to pass a new value (to **var COUNT_DEFAULT**) on js load from my new module.

*core js example:*

```
(function(_, $) { 

    var COUNT_DEFAULT = 2; 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you well, but you can do it like that.

```js
var module = (function (myVal) {
   var COUNT_DEFAULT = myVal || 2; 
   
   return {
      val: COUNT_DEFAULT
   };
});

var defaultVal = module();
var customVal = module(45);

console.log(defaultVal);
console.log(customVal);
```

Comment: the idea should be not change js content file. This new value to be set in variable COUNT_DEFAULT, can be permanent for all web application.

Comment: So I don't think it's possible.